# Managing transcript

Tags: chat, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots, livechattranscript, chattranscript

In Einstein chatbot, when we click save transcript, a file with filename 'Transcript' is being downloaded. The client is Asking if the Downloaded file can have Filename of TranscriptMMDDYYYY.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option to configuration post-chat transcript download message. Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdXSKUA3/allow-configuration-of-postchat-transcript-download-message).